# How can i associate the Image in a Folder with that User?

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a forum web site where Users can (No registration is required for users) can Upload the pictures .

I dont want to Store the pictures in the Database , so i am storing it on to a Folder in my server .

As part of Picture Upload , the user will enter their Mail id (Optional), Mobile Number (Optional ) , Name and the picture .

Once  this is done , as part of displaying Search Results in form of a Grid , how can i assciotae the Image with that User in the Stored  Folder ??

Please see the Image for understanding ??

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per your description name is required field and it should be unique. So you can store image as per the name of the user in one folder only. So that you can associate image based on the name of the user from one folder only. You have to keep one field which is unique among all users and you can associate fields like avata, DOB and many more.

Comment: No problem , Email can be kept mandatory and its Unique , Not a bad idea will try this way .Thanks .

Comment: @Gajjini .. Do let me know it works for you or not. If it works for you than please mark as an answer so that it will be heloful for others.